# Access hasMany/belongsTo relationship data with JSONAPI

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, json-api

Can you help me, please?

I have a model Channel, a model Feature, a model ChannelApplication and a model ApplicationFeature. And I defined them like this:

My model `channel.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  key: attr('string'),
  multiplePages: attr('boolean'),
  features: hasMany('feature', { async: true })
});
```

My model `feature.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  key: attr('string'),
  applicationFeatures: hasMany('application-feature', { async: true }),
  channels: hasMany('channel', { async: true })
});
```

My model `channel-application.js`:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo, hasMany } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  name: attr('string'),
  clientId: attr('string'),
  channel: belongsTo('channel'),
  applicationFeatures: hasMany('application-feature', { async: true })
});
```

My model `application-feature.js`

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';
import { belongsTo } from 'ember-data/relationships';

export default Model.extend({
  scope: attr('string'),
  connectType: attr('string'),
  channelApplication: belongsTo('channel-application', { async: true }),
  feature: belongsTo('feature', { async: true })
});
```

I'm using **JSONAPI**. And in my route I do this:

```
model() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      profiles: this.store.findAll('profile'),
      channels: this.store.findAll('channel'),
      channelApplications: this.store.query('channel-application', { filter: { feature: 'inbox'} })
   })
}
```

So, in my template I need to get my `ChannelApplications` and for each one I need to know `Channel` related with this `ChannelApplications` and know each `ApplicationFeature`.

```
{{#each channelApplications as |channelApplication|}}
    {{channelApplication.id}}

    // I think in something like this, but this doesn't work of course
    {{#each channelApplication.channels as |channel|}}
       <span>{{channel.id}}</span>
       <span>{{channel.name}}</span>
       {{#each channelApplication.applicationFeatures as |applicationFeature|}}
          <span>{{applicationFeature.id}}</span>
          <span>{{applicationFeature.name}}</span>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}

{{/each}}
```

**channelApplication.applicationFeatures** and **channelApplication.channels** returns nothing.

When I print `{{channelApplication.applicationFeatures.length}}` it return 0.

When I print `{{channelApplication.applicationFeatures}}` it prints a `<DS.PromiseManyArray>`

JSONAPI return for `channelApplications: this.store.query('channel-application', { filter: { feature: 'inbox'} })`:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "type":"channel-applications",
         "id":"2",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Application1",
            "channel-id":1,
            "client-id":"123"
         },
         "relationships":{
            "application-features":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "type":"application-features",
                     "id":"3"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"channel-applications",
         "id":"4",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Application2",
            "channel-id":2,
            "client-id":"456"
         },
         "relationships":{
            "application-features":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "type":"application-features",
                     "id":"7"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"channel-applications",
         "id":"5",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Application3",
            "channel-id":3,
            "client-id":"001"
         },
         "relationships":{
            "application-features":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "type":"application-features",
                     "id":"9"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"application-features",
                     "id":"10"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"application-features",
                     "id":"11"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"application-features",
                     "id":"12"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "included":[
      {
         "type":"application-features",
         "id":"3",
         "attributes":{
            "channel-application-id":2,
            "feature-id":3,
            "scope":"teste1, teste2, teste3",
            "connect-type":"script"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"application-features",
         "id":"7",
         "attributes":{
            "channel-application-id":4,
            "feature-id":3,
            "scope":"",
            "connect-type":"redirect"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"application-features",
         "id":"9",
         "attributes":{
            "channel-application-id":5,
            "feature-id":1,
            "scope":"teste4, teste5",
            "connect-type":"redirect"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"application-features",
         "id":"10",
         "attributes":{
            "channel-application-id":5,
            "feature-id":2,
            "scope":"",
            "connect-type":"password"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"application-features",
         "id":"11",
         "attributes":{
            "channel-application-id":5,
            "feature-id":3,
            "scope":"",
            "connect-type":"password"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"application-features",
         "id":"12",
         "attributes":{
            "channel-application-id":5,
            "feature-id":4,
            "scope":"",
            "connect-type":"password"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So, someone know about anything I'm doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is not correct `JSONAPI`. Also its not clear: Does a `channel-application` has one or multiple `channel`s?

Becuase `channel: belongsTo('channel'),` means it has one `channel` but then you don't should loop through them like `{{#each channelApplication.channels as |channel|}}`.

If you have one `channel` you can't return `"channel-id":1,` as an attribute, but *should* return a relationship:

```
channel: {
  data: {
    type: 'channel',
    id: '1'
  }
}
```